# Change state to hide Text

Tags: react-native

I want to hide an element.

In State I have:

```
    this.state = {
        showModal: false
    };
```

After the button:

```
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => { this.setState({ showModal: !this.state.showModal }); }}>
                
                <Image
                    source={{
                    uri:'my-url',
                    }}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

And the text:

```
            { !this.state.showModal && 
                <>
                    <Text>HELLO</Text>
                </>
            }
```

I click the button and nothing happens. The text is not hidden. What is my mistake?

Comment: Should work from the look of it, might get more context if you can post the whole component file with relevant snippets.

Comment: It's unclear can you please share the code ??